# Debian repository plugin for Artifactory?

Tags: jenkins, debian, artifactory

I have found a yum plugin that lets Artifactory serve as [a rpm repository](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/YUM+Repositories). Is there a similar plugin for the debian package repository?

ps. I deploy my software as deb packages as a part of the Continues Integration process with Jenkins and Artifactory.

Comment: a good repo would be very neat indeed. Sadly I haven't found one either :-(

Answer (score 11):

We are working on it :) Please cast your vote: https://issues.jfrog.org/jira/browse/RTFACT-4613

**Update Jul 13 2014:** The wait is over! [Artifactory 3.3 with Debian Support has been released!](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+3.3)

Comment: Please check out our most updated documentation space, where you’ll find more information on Debian support. Fully supported in Artifactory now: 
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Debian+Repositories

Comment: Do you have any plans to add Debian source package support to the Debian repos?

Answer (score 1):

I just released [dput-webdav](https://github.com/jhermann/artifactory-debian#package-uploading), so that you now can easily upload your packages into a [Debian repository hosted by Artifactory](https://github.com/jhermann/artifactory-debian#overview).